# Does stripe size in the ORC File dump represented in Compressed size Format?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, orc

We have snappy compressed generated ORC files. I'm just trying to understand the ORC File dump log, and I know that by default the stripe size for ORC would be 64MB. But, I see that each stripe in the ORC file in general has around 5-10MB in size. I just want to know if that sizes are represented in compressed format or my default stripe is itself lesser than 64MB?

Note: I'm using the latest EMR instance in the background and the files are in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe size denote the buffer memomry size which is assigned to change row storage to column storage and then write to HDFS. so alway you see your stripe in HDFS is lower than the size of your stripe(i.e. 64 MB).

Comment: post this as a comment

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, it did not answer my question completely. Why would there be a huge difference? and do you think that stripe size which represented in ORC file dump is actually in compressed size format?